# Variables are invalid json while using python requests on graphql

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphql

code

```
d = { 'operationName': 'CreateMessage', 'variables': { 'message': { 'content': 'hello world', 'pictureKeys': [], 'syncToPersonalUpdate': True } }, 'query': query }
print(d)

resp = requests.post(url, data=d, headers = headers, cookies = cookies)
print(resp)
print(resp.content.decode('utf-8'))
```

stdout:

```
{'operationName': 'CreateMessage', 'variables': {'message': {'content': 'hello world', 'pictureKeys': [], 'syncToPersonalUpdate': True}}, 'query': 'mutation CreateMessage($message: CreateMessageInput!) {\n  createMessage(input: $message) {\n    success\n    toast\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n'}
<Response [400]>
Variables are invalid JSON.
```

I'm new to graphql, what does this mean and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your dict to json

```
import json

resp = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(d), headers = headers, cookies = cookies)
```